# Amazon SQL job interview question: customers who made 2+ purchases -- is it doable in DAX?

Tags: sql, dax

You have a simple table that has only two fields: CustomerID, DateOfPurchase. List all customers that made at least 2 purchases in any period of six months. You may assume the table has the data for the last 10 years. Also, there is no PK or unique value.
One possible solution for this question is as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CustomerID
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2
              WHERE t2.CustomerID = t1.CustomerID AND
                    t2.DateOfPurchase > t1.DateOfPurchase AND
                    t2.DateOfPurchase <= DATEADD(month, 6, t1.DateOfPurchase));
```

**I was wondering if we can do something similar in DAX**. For the sake of simplicity, let's assume everything is in one table and there is no relationship.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You got me at

> For the sake of simplicity

Maybe this(?)

```
Table = 
SUMMARIZE(
FILTER(
    yourTable,
    VAR CurrentCustomerID = yourTable[CustomerID]
    VAR CurrentDateOfPurchase = yourTable[DateOfPurchase]
    RETURN
    NOT ISEMPTY(
            CALCULATETABLE(
                    VALUES(yourTable[CustomerID]),
                    ALL(yourTable),
                    yourTable[CustomerID] = CurrentCustomerID,
                    yourTable[DateOfPurchase] < CurrentDateOfPurchase,
                    yourTable[DateOfPurchase] >= EDATE(CurrentDateOfPurchase,-6)
                    )
            )
    ),
    yourTable[CustomerID]
)
```

Update

Since there are no more answers, I am sharing the simulated data so that someone else will be encouraged to respond and we can all learn something from this. Around 50,000 customers, 100,000 transactions, 10 years. Date format: MDY

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JPS4XHfpGSTXuNWIMdoPlp5Z1BqV9WGO/view?usp=sharing